# unknown type property when retrieving from firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from cloud firebase

model.ts

```
export interface Asignaturas {
    id: string;
    codigo: number; 
    nombre: string;
}
```

services.ts

```
export class AsignaturasService {
    asignatura: Observable<Asignaturas[]>;

    constructor(private db: AngularFirestore){}
    
    getAsignaturas() {
    return this.asignatura = this.db.collection('asignaturas').snapshotChanges()
     .pipe(
           map(
               docArray => {
                  return docArray.map(
                                      doc => {
                                         return {
                                            id: doc.payload.doc.id,
                                            codigo: doc.payload.doc.data().codigo,
                                            nombre: doc.payload.doc.data().nombre

                                         };
                                      }
                                  )
               }
           )
     )}//subscribe( res => console.log(res))};
}
```

In this above code i am trying to get properties for my interface Asignatura.
In console log i can see that values are retrieved correctly, however the app is throwing error

> ERROR in src/app/shared/asignaturas.service.ts(26,76): error TS2339: Property 'codigo' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
> src/app/shared/asignaturas.service.ts(27,76): error TS2339: Property 'nombre' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

Any idea what is wrong. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a type thing, your code doesn't know that those properties exist. You could create an interface that represents your doc and assert that type & doc.data() onto a new object, [Type casting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).
To make typescript happy you could do the below, but this will only give you protection at compile time. Not sure if this is what you're looking for.

```
doc => { 
    const data = doc.payload.doc.data() as Asignaturas
    return {
        id: doc.payload.doc.id,
        codigo: data.codigo,
        nombre: data.nombre
    };
}
```